# UWP User Controls project type

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Actually I have some UWP projects and need to refactor some redundant code.

In my GUI I have many times this portion of code

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Model.EstadoValidar.ListaInconsistencias }" Grid.Row="9">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descripcion}" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And need to convert it Custom control.

I add a new project named controls using WPF Control Library (.NET Framework), it doesn't recognize `ListView` or `GridView` Objects.

What kind of project must use to build my cust controls ?

Actually using VS 2017 15.3, project targets to .NET 4.6.2 / Standard 1.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A UWP app cannot reference a `WPF Control Library`. Only a WPF application can.

You cannot make a custom control that can be used on both UWP and WPF. Forget about this. UWP and WPF have different XAML stacks that can't be shared.

If you want to create a reusable UWP control you could create a `Class Library (Universal Windows)` project: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windowsapp/930/create-user-control-xaml-csharp